# is it effective using switch as dynamic and pagination like this?

Tags: php, php-7

i create dynamic and pagination using switch, is it effective if the code looks like this?

```
if(isset($_GET['pages'])){
    $pages = $_GET['pages'];

    switch ($pages) {
        case 'home':
            $totalData = count(query("SELECT * FROM tb_items"));
            $totalPage = ceil($totalData / $totalDataPerPage);
            $activePage = $_GET['page'];
            $earlyData = ( $totalDataPerPage * $activePage ) - $totalDataPerPage;
            $item = query("SELECT * FROM tb_items ORDER BY listing_time DESC LIMIT $earlyData, $totalDataPerPage");
            $cat = "home";
            include "ez/_ez.php";
            break;
        case 'items':
            $totalData = count(query("SELECT * FROM tb_items WHERE cat_id = 1"));
            $totalPage = ceil($totalData / $totalDataPerPage);
            $activePage = $_GET['page'];
            $earlyData = ( $totalDataPerPage * $activePage ) - $totalDataPerPage;
            $item = query("SELECT * FROM tb_items WHERE cat_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $earlyData, $totalDataPerPage");
            $cat = "items";
            include "ez/_ez.php";
            break;
        case 'worlds':
            $totalData = count(query("SELECT * FROM tb_items WHERE cat_id = 2"));
            $totalPage = ceil($totalData / $totalDataPerPage);
            $activePage = $_GET['page'];
            $earlyData = ( $totalDataPerPage * $activePage ) - $totalDataPerPage;
            $cat = "worlds";
            $item = query("SELECT * FROM tb_items WHERE cat_id = 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $earlyData, $totalDataPerPage");

            include "ez/_ez.php";
            break;
        default:
            echo "<center><h1>Maaf. Halaman tidak di temukan !</h1></center>";
            break;
    }
}else{
    include "ez/_ez.php";
}
```

is there a way to make this more effective?
help me if there any way to make it looks more good

Comment: _"is it effective using switch..."_ as opposed to what?

Comment: i mean the case looks like this, is it effective already?

Comment: I think this question better belongs to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You could also implement it using an abstract class and inherit that class for each type of page, but this is just another suggestion that is primarily opinion based so I think this question is a bit off-topic to this website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of repeating your code that much, you could store the page categories in an array:

```
$category_ids = ['home' => null, 'items' => 1, 'worlds' => 2];

if (isset($_GET['pages'])) {
  $cat = $_GET['pages'];

  if (array_key_exists($cat, $category_ids)) {
    $category_id = $category_ids[$cat];
    $where = !is_null($category_id) ? 'WHERE cat_id = ' . $category_id : '';

    $totalData = count(query("SELECT * FROM tb_items $where"));
    $totalPage = ceil($totalData / $totalDataPerPage);
    $activePage = $_GET['page'];
    $earlyData = ($totalDataPerPage * $activePage) - $totalDataPerPage;
    $item = query("SELECT * FROM tb_items $where ORDER BY listing_time DESC LIMIT $earlyData, $totalDataPerPage");
    include "ez/_ez.php";
  } else {
    echo "<center><h1>Maaf. Halaman tidak di temukan !</h1></center>";
  }
} else {
  include "ez/_ez.php";
}
```

Comment: thanks mate.
so that no need to use switch case anymore?

Comment: @RicEz In your case it isn't necessary, as the only thing that changes between cases is the category filter.